# Added Run Script phase to Xcode, but nothing happens

Tags: xcode, build

I added a Run Script build phase to my Xcode project, the script is just

```
echo "Hello"
```

I'm not seing hello in the debug console or anything, so I guess my script is not being executed when I build.

[image: Build Phases]

Any ideas ?

( Edit: The navigator just shows )

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1955.
**** UNIT TESTS ****
Success: 33 tests passed.
Test time: 0.02 seconds.
********************
[Switching to process 1955 thread 0x13c13]
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Xcode**: `View > Navigators > Reports`

The Report Navigator is the "chat bubble" in the Xcode sidebar.

[image: Report Navigator in Xcode]

Select your most recent `Build` from the sidebar on the left.

Then click `All Messages` in the tab bar to see the output of your Run Script Build Phase.

[image: View Run Script Build Phase output in Xcode 6]

Xcode Version changes:

- **Xcode 12**: `View > Navigators > Reports`
- **Xcode 6**: `View > Navigators > Show Report Navigator`
- **Xcode 5**: `View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator`
- **Xcode 4**: `View > Navigators > View Log Navigator`

Comment: **In `Xcode 11`, my test-target's `Run Script` does not show any `echo` where you mention!** maybe because script is arranged above `Compile Sources` (in `Build Phases`); Does anyone know how to ensure logs get visible in report-navigator?

Comment: For now was forced to work it around using **`exec > >(tee -a "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}.log") 2>&1`** (at top of script to backup logs manually, beside still logging on console, but other people may replace `${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}.log` part with another file-location). Also, add resulted `log`-file's path into your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: One gotcha is if you have more than 1 scheme. I think it lists them in alphabetical sort order. So make sure you're looking in the correct group which represents the scheme.

Answer (score 34):

You will see the output in the build log.

After build is finished:

- Go to "View -> Navigators -> Show Report Navigator" from menu,
- Or press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> shortcut (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> in older ExCode),
- Then check the latest log.

Comment: What you are looking at is debug log. This shows output as a result of running your program. What you should look at is "build log" which will show you output of the build process.

Answer (score 9):

The quickest way that I found is by using the below echo command in my Run Script with "warning:" in it. Xcode threw a warining. Hence confirmed your script is getting executed

```
echo "warning: RUN SCRIPT in ACTION"
```

you also can try `echo "error: RUN SCRIPT in ACTION"`

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6: `View -> Navigators -> Show Report Navigator`

On the left column, Under the `By Group` tab, select the latest `Build` for whatever target you just built.

In the middle column, select the `All Messages` tab, the output of your build script should be somewhere in there.