# Xcode external tools cpplint

Tags: xcode, plugins, lint, command-line-tool

Is there already a way in Xcode to map from a generic command line tool's output to line numbers and messages so that when running e.g. cpplint you can have it mapped to the graphical text editor?

I though of writing a plugin for this but it seems overkill, I imagined that this kind of generic functionality had already been developed, if not already included in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles upon this:
In Xcode 7 it's actually very easy to accomplish this behaviour. Add a "Run Script Phase" to the "Build Phases" of your target, as described very well on this [site here](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com). Then use the following command to run `cpplint.py`:

```
/usr/local/bin/cpplint.py ./${TARGET_NAME}/*
```

Adjust the path to `cpplint.py` to your situation. When `cpplint.py` encounters an error, Xcode should highlight the specific line in the editor like this:

[image: Cpplint error shown in Xcode Editor]

*Hint*: If you want to modify the command above, you can observe the entire output of the script in Xcode on the "Report Navigator". To view the "Report Navigator" press either `⌘8` or click on `View > Navigators > Show Report Navigator`, then select the last build on the right pane and activate `All Messages` on the log pane. See also the answer of the the following post: [Added Run Script phase to Xcode, but nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589365/added-run-script-phase-to-xcode-but-nothing-happens/18219518).

Comment: As of Xcode 10, this no longer seems to work :-(
Can anybody confirm this, or even bettter: has a workaround?