# Xcode 7: Where is "Log Navigator", as opposed to the "Report Navigator"?

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

The Apple docs mention the 'log navigator' [1] and says the output of a bash echo statement, created by a build phase, will be visible there [2]. However, in Xcode 7 I have never seen the 'log navigator', only the 'report navigator', and that window does not show my echo statement. How can I see the true log from within Xcode GUI? 
thank you!
Anne

1.[] Picture of log window; ; X.About the Log Navigator ; ; https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-log_navigator/articles/log_navigator-about.html

2.[] States that 'log' will show output from 'echo'; ; X.Running a Script While Building a Product ; ; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html

Answer (score 6):

From [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589365/added-run-script-phase-to-xcode-but-nothing-happens/18219518#18219518) (in the first answer), you can see a Xcode version history of the name of that navigator.  Before Xcode 6, it was called **Log Navigator**; from Xcode 6 on, it's called **Report Navigator**.

Comment: As for the "echo' not appearing, have you tried re-setting the scope (All/Recent) and filters (Erroes Only/All Issues/All Messages) at the top of the pane?

Comment: yes I tried resetting the scope and filters. The output appears on my jenkins console but I cannot find it on my xcode window. Have you tried it? This didn't work for me in xcode 6 either. I got so frustrated this time I decided to post to SO :).